# If I promote web hosting services whose users use it in the wrong way, is my commission haram?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software

I am an affiliate marketer. I promote website hosting offers on my website. Some hosting companies do not allow adult content hosting, others say: if there is no violation with the laws in their country, they will allow it. But both do not advertise the adult hosting services.

As a Muslim, I started thinking on what else can be hosted on servers. I found that many things can be hosted without having any conflict with web hosting providers. Like music, pictures (which may include nudity), content against Islam, etc.

My question is: if I promote web hosting services, is my commission haram because their clients, whom I forwarded to buy that services, are using it in a wrong way, or that is the web hosting provider responsibility in front of Allah?

Answer (score 1):

Well
Generally, affiliate is just business which is Halal and in some cases it can be Haram.

**Halal Affiliate**
Now come to thing that you are promoting something which is digital product or physical product. You need to check what is the product.
If a product which you are promoting and physical and doesn't have any Haram ingredients in it then it is Halal. If it is a digital product such as video, movie, e-book, etc... which has information and can help other people then it is Halal.

**Haram**
Now take same examples as above. If you are promoting physical thing and it has Haram ingredients or a digital product such as porn videos, movies, songs etc... then it is Haram.

Now you are promoting a web-hosting but you aren't administrator of it, Web-hosting can be used in both ways such as web-hosting for knowledgeable website or for haram "porn, wrong information..."  but you can't do anything against it so it isn't your problem in other case you could block.

You are also saying that some web-hosting doesn't allow adult content to be hosted on their servers so it would be better for your to promote their product.

*I hope I have covered everything*

Answer (score 0):

you are promoting web-hosting service, not clients of that service, so it is halal (since their sites do not promote bad things, as you said); but you can somehow support people (owners of that services) who themselves discourage haram things if you think that that is good, and discourage people who allow haram things; but that can be even bad because you will lose money, so it has bad sides and good sides and i am not sure that you should do that since it is halal (ie allowed). probably it depends on what you can afford ie whether you can easily refuse some money - probably you can afford that if you can find many clients whom you like, prefer, or find another additional job.